# Passing 'password expiration' information from Wildfly Server authentication module to remote EJB client

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jaas

We have a Wildfly 10 JEE application and a java fat client that uses remote EJ calls to communicate with the server. Authentication is done using a custom login module in the wildfly server.

Now we have the requirement to enhance this login module with the concept of a password expiration. Whenever a password expires the user has to change its password during the login process. The login module uses JAAS callbacks and the JAAS callback handler. As far as I've understood we could use the javax.security.auth.callback.TextInputCallback in our LoginModule to request the new password from the user while performing the login.

How does this integrate with remoting. How does our fat client receive the TextInputCallback to provide the requested input? I guess we have to register a custom CallbackHandler on client side that processes the callbacks but I have not found any documentation on how to do this with Wildfly. Can anybody give me a hint on such documentation or a sample on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you are going towards the wrong direction.
Using your approach of putting the password change into the LoginModule has some issue.

- User login is usually expected to be "safe" process i.e. process "without" side effects.
- Using the `TextInputCallback` to ask for a new passport is at least strange.
  The `TextInputCallback` is meant to ask the user for regular text not for a password for example a second authentication factor like a (timebased) PIN 
  A client implementing a `CallbackHandler` does not know that it's a password which may has has to be masked when shown on the scren.
- The approach violates the single responsibilty principle of the LoginModule - a LoginModule is responsible for log in / authenticate the user.

Keep in mind that usually for a password change you need an authenticated / authorized user which has to confirm the password change by re-entering his old password
and which usually also provides a second field where the user can re-enter his new password. Just one `xxxCallback` seems not be enough.

Even one should not use `Exceptions` for control flows I'd suggest to use a `CredentialExpiredException` to signal the client that the user has to change
the password. This is also the way Oracle does it in one of the [WebLogic JAAS Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/fat_client.html)

After all my remarks if you  still want / need to put it into the custom `LoginModule` then I'd suggest to define your own custom `Callback`s 
for example `PasswordChangeCallback` or `ConfirmPasswordCallback`, `NewPasswordCallback`, `VerifyNewPasswordCallback`

You can simply add them to custom `LoginModule` there is no need to register them. Keep in mind that standard clients may have problems whith these additional callbacks.
Your client then has to implement a the corresponding `CallbackHandler`.

In JAAS there are two ways to customise the used `CallbackHander` 
* by configuring a custom default CallbackHandler

From the [CallbackHandler API documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html)

> A default CallbackHandler class implementation may be specified in the
>   auth.login.defaultCallbackHandler security property. The security
>   property can be set in the Java security properties file located in
>   the file named /lib/security/java.security. 
>   refers to the value of the java.home system property, and specifies
>   the directory where the JRE is installed.

or by passing as argument to the constructor of the `LoginContext`.
The `LoginContext` provides two constructors which accept a `CallbackHandler`

```
public LoginContext(String name, CallbackHandler callbackHandler)
       throws LoginException


public LoginContext(String name, Subject subject,
       CallbackHandler callbackHandler) throws LoginException
```

see [LoginContext API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/LoginContext.html)

> How does it integrate with removing?

It should be the same way as you already do it. There is not much difference.

> How does our fat client receive the `TextInputCallback`?

Via `CallbackHandler` Interface similar to the `PasswordCallback`. You've mentioned that the Login Module uses the `CallbackHandler`.

```
  void  handle(Callback[] callbacks)
```

If you want to know how to implement the `handle` method the [`CallbackHandler` API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html) also provides an example of an implementation of the `CallbackHandler` `handle` method.